# Can't read new config variables in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, config, laravel-5.4

I added a new config variable to the `config/app.php` file in laravel like this

> `'foo'  => 'pass'`

but when I tried reading it using `config('app.foo')` I keep getting `null` while other variables return correct values. What do I need to do?

Comment: Please show full `app.php`

Comment: did you return that config array ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Syntax you're using is correct, try to clear configuration cache by using this command:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 4):

**Whenever you change config you must clear old cache**.

Laravel saves some common settings in cache e.g. config,packages and services in cache folder. If you face this kind of issue again with config or class not found issue in config/app.php etc then you should see your **cached config file (/laravel_project/bootstrap/cache/config.php)** to check if required thing is available or not.

Sometimes routes or views does not render changes when you are working on a **virtualhost** then you also need to clear the cache of that part.

To do so, we have to run multiple command like:

```
 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan view:clear
 php artisan route:clear
 php artisan config:clear
```

But writing these commands daily is annoying thing. So I have created a package for it.
https://github.com/afrazahmmad/clear-all-cached-data. install it and run:

```
php artisan clear:data
```

and it will run all above commands automatically.

Answer (score 0):

how to fix read config or env varaible return empty

1- write in config/app.php

return [

```
// project varaible
"FCM_serverkey" =>  'AAAA*************',
```

2- write same key at .env file
FCM_serverkey=AAAA*************

3- to return code from both place. formulat of write key is :         "app." + key
//read config
$apiKey = getenv('FCM_serverkey');
if( $apiKey == null    ) {
$apiKey = config('app.FCM_serverkey');
}

4- pull new code to server, then write clear cache config:
php artisan config:clear